# Tag persons in Facebook page post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I've written a Facebook web application, which is able to post links to the app page feed (as the page) by requesting the page token and doing a post request to the /PAGE_ID Graph REST endpoint. So far, so good, but I'd like to tag the links with their authors as well. When I add the **tags** parameter to this request with a value of *my* user id (I am an admin of the page), this works fine. But when I enter another user id (even one that *likes* the app page), no tagging is done. Does anyone have any experience with this? Some blog post suggest this is not possible using the Graph API, even though this *is* possible when done manually.

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of things that can be done “manually” are not possible via API. // And using `tags` is supposed to work only if you use `place` as well – and as far as I understand, it is only to be used to tag users that are at a physical location.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, it is no longer possible with the new version of the Facebook's API (v.2.0).
Refer to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396) for more informations.